# Is this structure make-able?

Tags: synthesis

I was wondering if it would be possible to make this chemical?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Any structure, is, in theory, make able. The real question is whether anyone would want to *waste* a sufficient amount of time to make it.

The structure you've drawn doesn't seem so unreasonable. With enough time planning a synthesis, and enough hours of graduate student time I see no reason to object

Comment: Well, many many molecules wouldn't  be possible even according to current theories.

Comment: And since you’re KC, you know all about Maitotoxin … wait, whoops, got your username wrong there ^^'

Comment: I do hope you're not putting maitotoxin into the category of *wasting* time Jan. It's a Nobel pursuit ;) plus it has so many rings to shade with clashing colours